# Apply to list of vectors

Tags: r, list, apply

I have list of numerical vectors (with different sizes each) in R. Let's say the list has 10 elements.

I would like to apply a function (something like `max(x - K, 0)` where `K` is a fixed constant) to each elements of each vector of the list, and get an output with exactly the same structure (thus a list of vectors).

I tried `sapply(data, function(x) max(x-K, 0))` but I get a vector of size 10. I don't know exactly what are its components by the way. I also tried `max(data-K,0)` directly, but I get an error message.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: To make your question clear, make a small reproducible example. Post some code to create a little list of 10 elements, show us what you tried, and show us what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
## dummy data
set.seed(1)
ll <- as.list(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10 * 10), ncol = 10)))

R> str(ll)
List of 10
 $ X1 : num [1:10] -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
 $ X2 : num [1:10] 1.512 0.39 -0.621 -2.215 1.125 ...
 $ X3 : num [1:10] 0.919 0.7821 0.0746 -1.9894 0.6198 ...
 $ X4 : num [1:10] 1.3587 -0.1028 0.3877 -0.0538 -1.3771 ...
 $ X5 : num [1:10] -0.165 -0.253 0.697 0.557 -0.689 ...
 $ X6 : num [1:10] 0.398 -0.612 0.341 -1.129 1.433 ...
 $ X7 : num [1:10] 2.4016 -0.0392 0.6897 0.028 -0.7433 ...
 $ X8 : num [1:10] 0.476 -0.71 0.611 -0.934 -1.254 ...
 $ X9 : num [1:10] -0.569 -0.135 1.178 -1.524 0.594 ...
 $ X10: num [1:10] -0.543 1.208 1.16 0.7 1.587 ...
```

With this, what you had is correct if you want an atomic vector output. To see the relationship look at the names of the vector elements

```
R> ( out <- sapply(ll, function(x, K) max(x - K, 0), K = 0.3) )
    X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9    X10 
1.2953 1.2118 0.6190 1.0587 0.5811 1.6804 2.1016 0.3107 0.8781 1.2868
```

they are in the same order as the names of the list elements:

```
R> names(out)
 [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10"
R> names(ll)
 [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10"
R> all.equal(names(out), names(ll))
[1] TRUE
```

If you want something back that looks like the original list, then use `lapply()` instead

```
R> lapply(ll, function(x, K) max(x - K, 0), K = 0.3)
$X1
[1] 1.295

$X2
[1] 1.212

$X3
[1] 0.619

$X4
[1] 1.059

$X5
[1] 0.5811
....
```

However, it is not clear that you want the maximum or the parallel maximum, i.e. for each list element a vector retuning `x - K` or `0`, whichever is larger, for each element of `x`. If you want this, that functionality is in the `pmax()` function:

```
R> lapply(ll, function(x, K) pmax(x - K, 0), K = 0.3)
$X1
 [1] 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 1.29528 0.02951 0.00000 0.18743 0.43832 0.27578
[10] 0.00000

$X2
 [1] 1.21178 0.08984 0.00000 0.00000 0.82493 0.00000 0.00000 0.64384 0.52122
[10] 0.29390

$X3
 [1] 0.6190 0.4821 0.0000 0.0000 0.3198 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.1179

$X4
 [1] 1.05868 0.00000 0.08767 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.80003
[10] 0.46318
....
```

or via `sapply`, which simplifies the reuslt to a matrix:

```
R> sapply(ll, function(x, K) pmax(x - K, 0), K = 0.3)
           X1      X2     X3      X4      X5      X6     X7     X8      X9
 [1,] 0.00000 1.21178 0.6190 1.05868 0.00000 0.09811 2.1016 0.1755 0.00000
 [2,] 0.00000 0.08984 0.4821 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.0000 0.0000 0.00000
 [3,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.0000 0.08767 0.39696 0.04112 0.3897 0.3107 0.87809
 [4,] 1.29528 0.00000 0.0000 0.00000 0.25666 0.00000 0.0000 0.0000 0.00000
 [5,] 0.02951 0.82493 0.3198 0.00000 0.00000 1.13302 0.0000 0.0000 0.29395
 [6,] 0.00000 0.00000 0.0000 0.00000 0.00000 1.68040 0.0000 0.0000 0.03295
 [7,] 0.18743 0.00000 0.0000 0.00000 0.06458 0.00000 0.0000 0.0000 0.76310
 [8,] 0.43832 0.64384 0.0000 0.00000 0.46853 0.00000 1.1656 0.0000 0.00000
 [9,] 0.27578 0.52122 0.0000 0.80003 0.00000 0.26972 0.0000 0.0000 0.07002
[10,] 0.00000 0.29390 0.1179 0.46318 0.58111 0.00000 1.8726 0.0000 0.00000
         X10
 [1,] 0.0000
 [2,] 0.9079
 [3,] 0.8604
 [4,] 0.4002
 [5,] 1.2868
 [6,] 0.2585
 [7,] 0.0000
 [8,] 0.0000
 [9,] 0.0000
[10,] 0.0000
```

Finally, note that it is good practice to pass into your function all information it needs to run. You are relying on R finding `K` somewhere. It is much better to have your anonymous function take an argument `K` and pass along the value of `K` you wish to use when you call the function. This is what I did above in my examples, e.g.

```
lapply(ll, function(x, K) pmax(x - K, 0), K = 0.3)
           |___________ FUN ___________| |_ ARGS_|
```

where the bit I have marked with `ARGS` is where you supply any further arguments required by the function supplied to argument `FUN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
somelist <- list()

somelist[[1]] <- sample(1:100,5)
somelist[[2]] <- sample(1:100,10)
somelist[[3]] <- sample(1:100,15)

k <- 50

somelistmod <- lapply(somelist, function(x) pmax(0,x-k))
```

Output -

```
> somelist
[[1]]
[1] 58 27 80 51 57

[[2]]
 [1]  72  81  57  79   2  74 100  49  46  16

[[3]]
 [1]  29  24  37  45  26  25  67  61  63  62  30  69  92  89 100

> somelistmod
[[1]]
[1]  8  0 30  1  7

[[2]]
 [1] 22 31  7 29  0 24 50  0  0  0

[[3]]
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0 17 11 13 12  0 19 42 39 50
```

The main difference is that you need to use `lapply` instead of `sapply`, and `pmax` instead of `max` to get a pairwise comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to return a list, you should use `lapply` instead of `sapply`. Furthermore, the function `max` takes the maximum of your vector `x`. Use `pmax`instead:

```
lapply(data,function(x) pmax(x-K,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `sapply` with `lapply` if you want to obtain a list:

```
lapply(data,function(x) max(x-K,0))
```