# Apply function over list of vectors

Tags: r, sapply

I have a list of vectors:

```
[[1]]
[1] 4 2 2  5 6 5 
[[2]]
[1] 30 9 320 2
...
[[99]]
```

I would like to apply a function over all of the vectors in the list.

```
sapply(1:99, function(x) listofvectors[[x]], max)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in FUN(1:99[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (.Primitive("max"))
```

I get the same error for `mean()` or any other function.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403985/apply-to-list-of-vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
sapply(1:99, function(x) max(listofvectors[[x]]))
```

or directly use

```
sapply(listofvectors, max)
```